# setting a localstorage high score and displaying it

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a tetris game that I am trying to finish but saving the high score after a game is over is causing me some issues. When the game ends, if the score is higher than what was previously saved as a highscore, it is supposed to save that new score as the high score locally and display that new highscore. I can not figure out why this is not happening. Below are the three different areas of my code that pertain to the high score. Any help would be appreciated.

creates the menu on the side of the game

```
 <div id="tetris">
<div id="menu">
  <p id="start"><a href="javascript:play();">Press Space to Play.</a></p>
  <p><canvas id="upcoming"></canvas></p>
  <p>score <span id="score">00000</span></p>
  <p>rows <span id="rows">0</span></p>
  <p>high score <span id="highscore">0</span></p>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas">
  Sorry, this example cannot be run because your browser does not support the &lt;canvas&gt; element
</canvas>
```

sets the high score when the game is over

```
var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");

  if (playing == false){
  if(highscore !==null){
      if(vscore > highscore) {
          localStorage.setItem("highscore", vscore);
      }
  }
  else{
      localStorage.setItem("highscore", vscore);
  }
  }
  else{
      null;
  }
```

updates the scores to display them

```
function play() { hide('start'); reset();          playing = true;  }
function lose() { show('start'); setVisualScore(); playing = false; }

function setVisualScore(n)      { vscore = n || score; invalidateScore(); }
function setScore(n)            { score = n; setVisualScore(n);  }
function addScore(n)            { score = score + n;   }
function clearScore()           { setScore(0); }
function clearRows()            { setRows(0); }
function setRows(n)             { rows = n; step = Math.max(speed.min, speed.start - (speed.decrement*rows)); invalidateRows(); }
function addRows(n)             { setRows(rows + n); }
function setHighScore(n)        { highscore = n; }
function addHighScore(n)        { setHighScore(highscore); }
function getBlock(x,y)          { return (blocks && blocks[x] ? blocks[x][y] : null); }
function setBlock(x,y,type)     { blocks[x] = blocks[x] || []; blocks[x][y] = type; invalidate(); }
function clearBlocks()          { blocks = []; invalidate(); }
function clearActions()         { actions = []; }
function setCurrentPiece(piece) { current = piece || randomPiece(); invalidate();     }
function setNextPiece(piece)    { next    = piece || randomPiece(); invalidateNext(); }

function reset() {
  dt = 0;
  clearActions();
  clearBlocks();
  clearRows();
  clearScore();
  setCurrentPiece(next);
  setNextPiece();
}

function update(idt) {
  if (playing) {
    if (vscore < score)
      setVisualScore(vscore + 1);
    handle(actions.shift());
    dt = dt + idt;
    if (dt > step) {
      dt = dt - step;
      drop();
    }
  }
}
```

I can add the full game code if needed but these are the three areas that directly pertain to the high score issue.

Comment: when you say `sets the high score when the game is over` can you paste the whole function? because I can not see where are you getting those parameters.

Comment: I see that the localStorage is being set when a "highscore" is achieved, but are you ever setting the highscore in the DOM? e.g. `document.getElementById('highscore').text = localStorage.getItem("highscore")`? e.g. calling setHighScore() once a hs is achieved?

Comment: @PrinceHernandez this section  if (playing == false){
  if(highscore !==null){
      if(vscore > highscore) {
          localStorage.setItem("highscore", vscore);
      }
  }            sorry im new i don't know how to paste this anywhere its easier to read

Comment: @bigbitecode that is the part I'm not sure how to do, recalling the highscore after it has been set and displaying it

Comment: @javascript896362 Well, without much context, it's hard to say, but I'd add just before the end of the `if(playing) { ... }` close another if check to see if the score or vscore is > highscore. I'll follow this comment up with a post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function update(idt) {
  if (playing) {
    if (vscore < score)
      setVisualScore(vscore + 1);
    handle(actions.shift());
    dt = dt + idt;
    if (dt > step) {
      dt = dt - step;
      drop();
    }
    // Add the following to update the highscore while playing.
    if (score > highscore) {
        setHighScore(score);
    }
  }
}

setHighScore = (score) => {

  // update highscore
  highscore = score;

  // update it visually?
  document.getElementById('highscore').text = highscore;
}
```

Then somewhere you'd want a check once the game is over -- I'd assume immediately where you set the playing boolean to false.

```
if (playing === false){
    if(vscore > highscore) {
      // For future games.
      localStorage.setItem("highscore", vscore);
    }
}
```

edit : 
I'm typing this on my phone, so apologies if format is wonky.
See example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVEJJW

Comment: added that all in and it still doesn't seem to save the score when the game ends